# How can I get my filepath when inside a controller action method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have seen the following code:

```
    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
        var filePath = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.FilePath;
    }
```

However is there an easier way to do this from inside of an action method in ASP MVC?

For example for www.test.com/abc  I would like to get "/abc"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its pretty straight forward.

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
     var filePath = Request.FilePath;

     //other stuff
}
```